# What are the "ordinary" (e.g. arithmetic) consequences of the universe axiom?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Consider the first-order theory obtained by adjoining to ZFC (or, better, Mac Lane set theory) the Grothendieck–Verdier (or Bourbaki?) universe axiom:

- For each set $x$ there exists a Grothendieck universe $\mathbf{U}$ with $x \in \mathbf{U}$.

Of course, this is strictly stronger than ordinary ZFC because it proves $\textrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. In fact, it proves $\textrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}))$, $\textrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})))$, and so on, as well as variants where $\mathsf{Con}$ is replaced by stronger notions of consistency.  On the other hand, this can be rephrased in terms of Gödel numbers as a number-theoretic proposition (and if I understand correctly, even as the existence of solutions for a Diophantine equation), and so these are examples of arithmetic consequences of the universe axiom.

However, this feels somewhat contrived. What I want to know is this:

**Question.** Is there a down-to-earth statement in ordinary mathematics (algebra, number theory, finite combinatorics, real analysis, etc.) that is decided by the universe axiom?

Comment: Now when you say "down-to-earth", I suppose you don't mean "Zero sharp exists", or so on; but rather some real life arithmetical/analytical statement? Because Mostowski absoluteness theorem comes to mind (it's like Shoenfield, but weaker, and with less assumptions).

Comment: I don't understand what $0^\sharp$ is, so that surely can't be down-to-earth!

Comment: I can't understand the Riemann Hypothesis! Is that not down to earth? :-)

Comment: Nope, I don't understand that either. (It would be extremely surprising if it does turn out to be decided by the universe axiom, however!) I guess what I want to understand is how it is that the existence of "big" sets can affect "small" sets.

Comment: Well, if $0^\#$ exists then (*lightface*) $\Sigma^1_1$ games are determined, and then some. But these are stronger assumptions than universes axiom; and you may disagree with the down-to-earth-ness of their consequences.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you are only interested in direct implications as opposed to consistency statements? There are interesting (for ordinary mathematics) models that one can build if one is allowed to use inaccessible cardinals. For example, if you have an inaccessible cardinal, you can build a model of set theory where a decent amount of Martin's axiom holds and all projective sets have the Baire property and are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Solovay's result. That does not count as a statement in ordinary mathematics to me.

Comment: As I know, the original proof of FLT uses Universes. But *maybe* much less (PA?) is required.